# How to get all the data from the inventory slots?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, im making a game in C# and im trying to get all the data from my inventory slots.

```
public bool AddItems(Item item){
            if(item == null || item.quantity <= 0)
                return false;

            List<Slot> listSlots = GetSlots(panel_Backpack.grid);
            if(listSlots.Count <= 0)
                return false;

                Slot slotFound = listSlots.FirstOrDefault(p => p.currentItem != null && p.currentItem.stackable && p.currentItem.quantity + item.quantity <= item.quantityMax);
                
                if(slotFound != null && slotFound.currentItem.itemId == item.itemId){
                    slotFound.currentItem.quantity += item.quantity;
                    slotFound.Refresh();
                } else {
                    slotFound = listSlots.FirstOrDefault(p => p.currentItem == null);
                    if(slotFound == null){
                        print("Inventory full!");
                        return false;
                    }
                    slotFound.ChangeItem(item);
                }

                return true;
        }
```

i make this code but im using the function FirstOrDefault() and I can only get the values ​​of the first slot.
i need to check all slots because when i pick up an item from the ground it sends it to a new slot if the item is different

but if the item in the first slot is not full (each slot takes two items) and i pick up items it always creates new slots because it sees that the first one is not its full

[EXAMPLE 1: I picked up a stone, a stone again and then a 2 squares.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiSsq.png)

[EXAMPLE 2: I picked up a stone, a square and then a square again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVsRy.png)

I want the squares to go to the same slot.

if anyone can help i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to check if the Item type matches the slot's item type when you are checking FirstOrDefault instead of after. If you do it after it does not affect the list search.

> Slot slotFound = listSlots.FirstOrDefault(p => p.currentItem != null && p.currentItem.stackable && p.currentItem.quantity + item.quantity <= item.quantityMax);

You use `slotFound.currentItem.itemId == item.itemId` to compare later in the method so if we instead move it into the FirstOrDefault search it should work. I am also just going to split the statement into multiple lines for ease of reading.

```
Slot slotFound = listSlots.FirstOrDefault(p => 
p.currentItem != null && 
p.currentItem.itemId == item.itemId && 
p.currentItem.stackable && 
p.currentItem.quantity + item.quantity <= item.quantityMax);
```

by checking the Slot Item has the same ID as the Item you are checking against in the FirstOrDefault() you will only get slots of the same "type". this should return the first slot that **Stores The Same Item** and is not full, or the default item if it can't find one.

Comment: yes, i want to check if the Item type matches, but i already did it and it works i guess, my problem is when the type doesnt match and the slot its not full, like my EXAMPLE 2. because im checking the first slot and i need to check all slots that contain a Item

Comment: try adding the extra bool expression in your FirstOrDefault that I mentioned.
> p.currentItem.ItemID == item.ID
I did not notice you were already checking if they were the same, that's my bad I will update my answer with this new information.

Comment: it worked with this bool, thank you

Comment: @iconic404 if it worked, accept the answer that way if others have a similar question, they will know this worked for you.